# creating a view of a gallery of images

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, media

I need to create a view of galleries of images.

The requirement is for a user to click on the menu item "albums". This then renders a view of a selected image from each of the galleries. Each gallery is made up of related images, each image is a content type which contains information about the image such as place taken description and category(this is the related field).

So the requirements are...

- Albums: Grid view of galleries using a selected image from each
  gallery.
- Galleries: Grid view of images including meta data (from image
  content type)

Clicking on each image in the gallery renders a colorbox.

When creating a gallery of images the user needs to be able to select which image is used as the displayed thumbnail in album view of galleries. This CANNOT be related to a date field or creation order. in other words a tickbox or something to be used to promote it to the gallery view. This image might be changed regularly so basing it on dates. etc is not feasable

We are talking a large number of images. they will initially be uploaded using the feeds importer + bulk media uploader (or ftp).

I have played with as many configurations as I can and cannot get the result I want.

The end users are not confident computer users so the system to add new images must be non complex. which is one of the reasons I am avoiding taxonomy as the category plus we could not get a taxonomy view to allow us to select an image as the promoted image. I also could not work out how to have taxonomy terms auto created as well. Which means I want people to be able to set the category by simply typing into the category field rather than first having to create a category and then select it from a drop down field.

One way I have considered is to make a gallery a content type and then embed into it a view of related images, The relationship would be on category. this of course is similar to pre-creating the taxonomy.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal Module [Album Photos](https://www.drupal.org/project/photos) best suits your need.

Comment: One of the first modules we tried. Perhaps I didn't do it right but it appears to be do it our way or the highway. Layout appears to be fixed to a vertical list and as the image is not a content type I have no idea how I am meant to import the images? the first lot of images contains 2000 images in multiple categories. I also am unable to add custom fields to each image. you are restricted to title and description. so unfortunately it does not fit the bill. no gallery we have tried does.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Mediabox](https://www.drupal.org/project/mediabox) module the problem with this module is that it's in dev state but it have type with fields support where you can put Term reference field with auto completion for category creation also one Featured taxonomy field with a check box for which image to be featured in Album grid.

One problem with this module and large number of images is that it use quite annoying browser like interface for adding images which get cluttered quite fast also crop that I don't found a way to switch off.